# _snprintf_s invokes [applicaiton].exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, mfc

_snprintf works ok. But why _snprintf_s triggered the breakpoint. Is there any mistake/ or i am missing something very important.

```
std::string hash_sha256_sa(const std::string source)
{
    const int  HASH_STRING = 64;
    const int HASH_RAW = 32;

    unsigned char _hash[HASH_RAW];
    memset(_hash, 0, HASH_RAW);

    sha256(_hash, (unsigned char*)&source[0], (unsigned long)source.length());

    std::string str(HASH_STRING, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_RAW; ++i)
    {
       //_snprintf_s(&str[i * 2], HASH_STRING, _TRUNCATE, "%02X", _hash[i]); //Failed

       //_snprintf(&str[i * 2], HASH_STRING,"%02X", _hash[i]); //Works              
     }

     return str;
}
```

Second variant provide the same result. _snprintf works ok. but _snprintf_s results following error

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buffer' was
>   corrupted.

```
 std::string hash_sha256_sa(const std::string source)
 {
     const int  HASH_STRING = 64;
     const int HASH_RAW = 32;

     unsigned char _hash[HASH_RAW];
     memset(_hash, 0, HASH_RAW);

     sha256(_hash, (unsigned char*)&source[0], (unsigned long)source.length());

     char buffer[HASH_STRING + 1];

     for (int i = 0; i < HASH_RAW; ++i)
     {
        _snprintf_s(&buffer[i * 2], _countof(buffer), _TRUNCATE, "%02X", _hash[i]);

       //_snprintf(&buffer[i * 2], _countof(buffer), "%02X", _hash[i]);

     }

     std::string str(buffer);
     return str;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending `buffer` to `_snprintf_s`, rather you are sending `&buffer[i * 2]`. At each increment, the available size for `&buffer[i * 2]` will decrease by 2. So change to the 2nd parameter as follows:

```
_snprintf_s(&buffer[i * 2], _countof(buffer) - i * 2, _TRUNCATE, "%02X", _hash[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`_snprintf_s` is a Microsoft-provided "safe" version of the function. If it's triggering a breakpoint, then you are doing something wrong in the function call, and the error is intended to help you detect that bug. `_snprintf` is unsafe and works by accident (because it is actually relying on undefined behavior).

In this case, you're clearly passing the wrong length for the buffer (the second parameter to the function). Although `str` does indeed have a total length of `HASH_STRING`, you are indexing into the buffer (`str[i * 2]`) and returning a pointer to that sub-buffer. Obviously, the sub-buffer cannot have the same length as the total buffer!

Comment: if going with first implementation you are correct but what about second implementation. Where sizeof(buffer) is used, but the error is stack around buffer is corrupted. snprintf is not working by accident. i guess i am missing something in _s variant of snprintf.

Comment: Same problem, of course. You're still passing the entire size of the buffer when you do `_countof(buffer)`, but you're only passing a pointer to a sub-string within the buffer. You are lying to the `_snprintf_s` function about the actual length of the buffer it is being given. Yes, `_snprintf` is still working completely by accident. It just doesn't have the error checking that `_snprintf_s` does, so it's unable to catch the bug. @rahul

Comment: you are right, as pointed by @BamakShmirani actual size of the buffer must be decremented on each loop execution. Is some thing important is left to be focused, then please point